# Prevent Yarn install from running in project (i.e. force NPM install)

Tags: npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

We recently switched back to using NPM from Yarn, but old habits die hard and I'm worried some devs will accidentally use `yarn install`.

How can I prevent `yarn install` from being run in the project? Or, even better, display a reminder to use `npm install`?

I'm thinking the `yarn install` can be intercepted with a `preinstall` script, but I'm not sure what to look for in the `preinstall` script.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I thought of another option, using the fact that Yarn will check its version against `$.engines.yarn` in `package.json`. If you set this as follows:

```json
{
  ...
  "engines": {
    "yarn": "use npm!"
  }
}
```

Yarn will bail out, albeit with a slightly cryptic error message:

```
yarn install v{foo}
info No lockfile found.
[1/5]   Validating package.json...
error {bar}@{baz}: The engine "yarn" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "use npm!". Got "{foo}"
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: While it's cryptic, I like this solution better for it's simplicity.

Comment: You can improve readability of the error message a little bit by using something like `"\n\nUse NPM!\n\n"`. Then the Use NPM notice is visible in its own prominent line (Maybe `\r\n` is needed to satisfy Windows, don't know).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with yarn 3 :(

Answer (score 11):

You can see whether it's Yarn or NPM running by looking at the value of the `npm_execpath` environment variable. If you did something like:

```json
"preinstall": "if [[ $npm_execpath =~ 'yarn' ]]; then echo 'Use NPM!' && exit 1; fi",
```

Then `yarn install` (or just `yarn`) would fail prior to the install step. If you want to make this cross-platform or you're not using *nix, then you could write a simple script like:

```js
#! /usr/bin/env node

if (process.env.npm_execpath.match(/yarn/)) {
  console.log("Use NPM!");
  process.exit(1);
}
```

and run that in `preinstall`.