# package.json disable "npm install"

Tags: npm-install, yarnpkg, package.json

Is there any way to disable the command `npm install` or `npm i` on a project through the `package.json` config?

I'm using `yarn` to add and install npm dependencies, and I want to force to not use `npm install`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force yarn install instead of npm install for Node module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076172/force-yarn-install-instead-of-npm-install-for-node-module)

Comment: Or flip the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58087572/3001761