# How can I forbid package contributors from using yarn to install dependencies?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg, dependency-management

I'm managing a package that recently used yarn for dependency management, but due to various problems I'm moving back to using npm. To help contributors, I want them to see an error if they try to install dependencies with yarn. This isn't strictly necessary as their contributions will be flagged at the code review stage, but to reduce their frustratation I want to let them know early on that yarn is no longer allowed.

However, it's important that other projects can import us with yarn - this restriction must **only apply to contributors to this package**.

### What I've tried

Using the `engines` field in `package.json` doesn't work (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58087572/5009210) because then my package refuses to install as a dependency for other projects.

Similarly, checking the npm execpath variable during a preinstall script (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57329003/5009210) breaks installations from other projects as the script also gets run during their install procedure.

### What I need

I need some way in the preinstall script to distinguish between local contributors, and installations of my package as a dependency. So I need a function to go here:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

// This script runs during the npm "preinstall" hook

const isYarn = () => process.env.npm_execpath.includes('yarn');
const isLocalDev = () => /* ??? */;

if (isYarn() && isLocalDev()) {
  console.error('Yarn not allowed for dependency management!');
  process.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did experiment with this option:

```js
// compare the current working directory, which should be my project root
// to the cwd where the original install script was run, which is either my project root
// or the root of a project that uses my package
const isLocalDev = () => process.cwd() === process.env.INIT_CWD;
```

...but this might not be very reliable as the install script can be run from anywhere in the project tree, so I'd need to do a bit more logic to figure out how INIT_CWD truly behaves.

Here's the approach I used instead:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

// My cypress dir is not part of the published package, 
// so if it's present then we must be doing local dev.
const isLocalDev = () => fs.existsSync('./cypress');
```

This only works if your `package.json` specifies published directories with the `"files"` option (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/package-json#files). Just make sure you choose a directory or file that is not part of your published package, and this solution works like a dream, even if you run yarn in a subdirectory.

I hope you found this trick useful!